# How to gather all entries for a specific value with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a simple way to get all available date for a specific ID. I used to use a heavy process based on unique IDs and transpose in Google Sheet. It's not performant at all as there is about 10.000 entries, it's taking about 5min to render in Google Sheet. So trying to get something similar using Python and Pandas with my basic knowledge... ;)

Here is a sample dataframe example and what I wanting to achieve :

```
    date        email
0   2001-01-01  email1@email.com
1   2002-01-01  email1@email.com
2   2003-01-01  email2@email.com
4   2004-01-01  email2@email.com
5   2005-01-01  email1@email.com
... ... ...
```

I need to get something like

```
email1@email.com    2001-01-01, 2002-01-01, 2005-01-01
email2@email.com    2003-01-01, 2004-01-01
```

I've tested several Panda's functions without success.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: ```df.groupby("email").agg(",".join)``` ?

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy, sounds good! Just wondering if it is possible to get the date in different columns ?

Comment: Maybe this: `pd.crosstab(df.email, df.date)` ?

Comment: @DavideBrex, thanks, problem with this that I get as much columns as much entries I have. Tested on a sample and got 3475 rows × 3970 columns

Comment: It's setting all date values as columns names, and 0 or 1 as value

Comment: Yes because if you want to have one column for each date, there will be a lot of columns and some cells will contain Nan. Try also this: `df.pivot(index="email", columns="date",values="date")`

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried it, but got `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`, that's why I was looking for some other option. I've also tried `df5 = df5.set_index(['email','date']).sort_index()`, where I'm able to get each date associated for a specific email but still in the same col. Maybe I could managed my problem with that but I'm not sure who to access couple of values.

Comment: I've tried : `df5.groupby("email").agg(",".join)
df5['date'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: "date"+str(x+1))` but I get a `KeyError: 'date'` error

Comment: The last thing you tried works with my dummy table. Try: `df= df.groupby("email").agg(",".join);
df = df['date'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: "date"+str(x+1))`

Comment: Also worked for me. Don't know why it didn't worked at first, I might have some conflictual history. Thanks @DavideBrex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers!

I finally achieved it using :

```
df= df.groupby("email").agg(",".join)
df = df['date'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: "date"+str(x+1))
```